# How can I get Pandas 1.4.2 on Kaggle

Tags: python, pandas, kaggle

```
     # Making a group with the age and the Survived
    age_survived = titanic_df.groupby("Survived", as_index=False)["Age"].value_counts()
    
    #Filtering Values
    survived_over_30 = age_survived [age_survived.Age > 30] #People with age more than 30
    survived_under_30 = age_survived [age_survived.Age < 30] #People with age less than 30
    
    survived_over_30 = survived_over_30 [survived_over_30.Survived == 1] #Getting only the values where the people survived
    survived_under_30 = survived_under_30 [survived_under_30.Survived == 1] #Getting only the values where the people survived
    
    #Plotting the difference
    #Making the graph
    fig = go.Figure()
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=survived_over_30.Age, boxpoints=', palette= [not_survived_color, survived_color])all', name='Survived Over 30',
                        fillcolor='blue', jitter=0.5, whiskerwidth=0.2,))
    fig.add_trace(go.Box(y=survived_under_30.Age, boxpoints='all', name='Survived Under 30',
                        fillcolor='red', jitter=0.5, whiskerwidth=0.2))
    
    # Customising the graph
    fig.update_layout(title='Survival of people under and over 30', 
                      yaxis=dict(gridcolor='rgb(255, 255, 255)',
                     gridwidth=3),
                     paper_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)',
                     plot_bgcolor='rgb(243, 243, 243)')
```

This is the code which works completely fine in Pandas 1.4.2 which is on my local machine. But on kaggle there is Pandas 1.3.5 which gives an error

```
'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'value_counts'
```

I wanna get pandas 1.4.2 on pandas

Comment: I think you can do `titanic_df.groupby("Survived", as_index=False)["Age"].apply(pd.Series.value_counts)`? But to answer the question, you can install additional/newer packages via `!pip install ...` from the notebook (cf. [this post](https://www.kaggle.com/questions-and-answers/36982)).

Comment: I tried pip install pandas and pip install pandas3 but none of them worked